Getting this error "SyntaxError: Named export 'useClickAway' not found" in nextjs when using storefront ui
I installed storefront ui and i am getting this error whenever i use any storefrontui block

SyntaxError: Named export 'useClickAway' not found. The requested module 'react-use' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'react-use';
const { useClickAway: c, useKey: i } = pkg;
i tried going finding the useClickAway and exporting it but it didnt work

What version of react-use in your package.json?

When importing from react-use try to import directly from the lib.
Mostly the issue:
import { useClickAway } from 'react-use'
The fix would be:
import useClickAway from 'react-use/lib/useClickAway' rather than
